# Implementing target-specific variable assignment in AIX's native make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target, aix

I have a main makefile (common for all platforms on which my software is deployed on) and a platform specific makefile containing AIX specific settings. The platform makefile is included at the end of the main makefile.

The main makefile defines a macro `A=somevalueA` that I want to override with a new value `somenewvalue` in the context of a few (not all) targets defined in the main makefile, for AIX. This makes it easier to visualize:

```
# main makefile

A=somevalueA
C=$(C1) $(A) $(C2)
B1=$(B11) $(C) $(B12)
B2=$(B21) $(C) $(B22)
B3=$(B31) $(C) $(B32)
B4=$(B41) $(C) $(B42)
target1:
  # some recipe using $(B1)

target2:
  # some recipe using $(B2)

target3:
  # some recipe using $(B3)

target4:
  # some recipe using $(B4)

include aixmakefile
```

Now suppose I want to override the value of `A` on AIX for targets `target1`, `target2` only. With gmake, I can simply add the following target-specific variable assignments in aixmakefile:

```
# aixmakefile
...
target1: A=somenewvalue
target2: A=somenewvalue
```

But this is not supported by AIX's native make program. Alternatives to target-specific assignment that come to my mind are:

1. Copying the definitions of `B1`, `B2` to aixmakefile and substituting occurrences of `$(A)` with `somenewvalue` (`$(A)` is guaranteed to be "at the end of a word" as described in [this article on gmake substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html), which is also true for AIX's native make):

```
# aixmakefile
...
B1=$(B11:$(A)=somenewvalue) $(C:$(A)=somenewvalue) $(B12:$(A)=somenewvalue)
B2=$(B21:$(A)=somenewvalue) $(C:$(A)=somenewvalue) $(B22:$(A)=somenewvalue)
```

2. Copying the entire recipe for targets `target1`,`target2` to aixmakefile and substituting occurrences of `$(A)` with `somenewvalue`:

```
# aixmakefile
...
target1:
  # some recipe using $(B1:$(A)=somenewvalue)
target2:
  # some recipe using $(B2:$(A)=somenewvalue)
```

As you can see, these approaches are not very elegant. I was wondering if there is a neat hack to implement target-specific variable assignments in AIX's make or some other concise, elegant solution to my problem that eludes me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Descriptions like "neat hack" and "concise, elegant solution" are in the eye of the beholder.  However the way this is done with traditional implementations of make is to use recursion: that is the makefile recipe will re-invoke `$(MAKE)` with the variable set as per the specific target.  Another "neat hack" (at least IMO) is to just require GNU Make.  It compiles and works just fine on AIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a well-defined relationship between the target names and the value, **AND** you don't need the "inheritance" feature of target-specific variables, you can just use constructed variable names:

```
C = $(C1) $($@_A) $(C2)
  ...
target1_A = somevalueA
target2_A = somevalueA
target3_A = somevalueA
target4_A = somevalueA
```

Now in `aixmakefile` you can set:

```
target1_A = somenewvalue
target2_A = somenewvalue
```

The `$@` in `$($@_A)` will expand to the target name (`target1`, `target2`, etc.) and so it will expand to `$(target1_A)` etc.

You can read more about metaprogramming in make here: https://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/ but note only the earliest parts of this are really portable: the newer/more powerful parts require GNU Make.